# erl_nif.h not found

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

I try to use erlang nif,

I made:

```
#include <erl_nif.h>
```

But get error:

fatal error: erl_nif.h: No such file or directory

Where can i find it? I have installed erlang R14B (erts-5.8.1)

OS Arch linux.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compile with `-I/usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.8.1/include`, if that's where `erl_nif.h` is.

Comment: I like to add a variables to my `~/.bash_profile`. For my installation (made by brew) I've added: `export ERLHOME=/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/17.5` and `export ERLINCL=$ERLHOME/lib/erlang/usr/include`. In this way I can just specify: `-I$ERLINCL`.

Comment: Set `C_INCLUDE_PATH `, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html